# Send message to slack HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, slack

I am trying to create a small webpage that has a field for text to be entered and a button to send. When the user hits the send button a script will run that sends the text to a slack channel. I have a API token but I am unsure on how to implement this using JS. I so far have the below, I know im close so if anyone can help be much appreciated.

**HTML Button to send message**

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send slack Message</button>
```

**Script to send message**

```
var path_to_call = 'http://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=my+token+xxxxxxxxx&channel=#testchannel&text=Thisisatest';

request(path_to_call, function(error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
         console.log('Success');
     } else { 
         console.log(error);
     }
});
```

Comment: You will need to add an event on the button which will fire the request

Comment: be careful with using slack tokens like this in java script, since your code incl. the token will be visible in the browser and can be stolen easily. Better do server side scripting.